# Best oracle version for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, oracle11g

I have develop the application using following

.NET FrameWork 4.0
MVC 3.0
sql server 2008 R2

now i have change the SQL server to Oracle.successfully migrate schema and data sql to oracle. successfully connected to oracle database but some queries give error.
Please tell me the best oracle version which run application smoothly.
I am using Oracle 11.2.0.1.0

for exmple when i access this query its give error.Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 does not support APPLY

```
return (from ac in db.action
let dbobj = db.table.Where(X => X.tableid == 15).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: why you down the point if you have reason please mention here.

Comment: probably down vote is for the title, you might have named your question like: "Migration from MSSQL Server 2008 to Oracle 11gR2"

Comment: i have successfully migrate schema and data into oracle and connect application with oracle.but when i run the application and access page its give error. Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 does not support APPLY. now you tell the title of question.

Comment: I don't really understand you. Tell us what you have done so far and what doesn't work well

Comment: i have update the question please see and help.

Comment: Though the error message "Oracle 11.2.0.1.0 does not support APPLY" clearly tells you that it is a problem with the query to the database, you do not show us the underlying sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL dialect and MSSQL Server SQL dialect have differences, for example, To query from empty space you have to:

- For MSSQL: `select 1`
- For Oracle: `select 1 from dual`

There are a log of other differences. So, you need to convert your MSSQL queries into Oracle queries. In luck, SQL Developer has pre-built tools to perform migration from MSSQL to Oracle. Check [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/migration/sqlserver-095136.html) out to find out more.

Comment: i have successfully migrate the sql schema and data in oracle. i connect to oracle successfully connected but some queries give error.

Comment: What do you mean? you rewrite all your queries from `mssql` to `oracle`?

Comment: That's the point, you have use the pre-built tools to migrate from mssql to oracle. Oracle SQL dialect has differences from MSSQL SQL dialect, for example, oracle can't query like this:`select 1`, oracle uses the `dual` table to query like this:`select 1 from dual`, also Oracle doesn't supply `TOP` and there are many other differences.

Comment: any tool which change the queries according to oracle,

Comment: As I said you have to use SQL Developer, see the link in the response